# Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" causes internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Our assets are in a sub domain and in order to overrun security features of our platform so we can add a Json query we have to add the following htaccess code

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

However the last line "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" creates an internal server error on my local machine, which is odd because we do not get the same error on our prod environment. We are using Apache 2.2.22  php 5.4.3.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Did you check the error log?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you do not have mod_headers enabled?

Secondly I think you may want to put the IfModule block outside the FilesMatch block. Like so

```
# Allow access from all domains for web fonts
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Code taken directly from https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess#L45